# Error when using Realm with Xcode 6.3.1

Tags: swift, cocoapods, realm

Today i decided to give a go to Realm for a project, but, when adding it via cococa pods, it just keeps yelling me he can't find **Realm.Private** on the  **ListBase** class.

tried to  clean, tried to reimport, closed & reopened Xcode....

content of my cocoapods file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'RealmSwift'
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [an issue on Realm's GitHub repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1881) about that.
Realm Swift's podspec makes use of some brand new CocoaPods features, so you will need to update CocoaPods to at least 0.37.1.

Cleaning the cache and the existing installation and re-installing has proven to be helpful in that case:

```
rm -r Pods/Realm
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Released/Realm
pod install
```

Comment: thank you!.  they should fix this, or put some troubleshooting.